# Null date is displaying as 01/01/0001 in code behind of ASP.Net page

Tags: c#

i am fetching the date by below code from db using c# ,how to check null date .when date is null then it shows default date on page 01/01/0001

```
IssueDate = dataReader.GetValue<DateTime>(DbColumnNames.PLAST_ISSUE_DT)
```

Comment: Try `dataReader.GetValue<DateTime?>`

Comment: If you want to be able to check for null values, you need to use a nullable type. See duplicates.

Comment: @GuruStron - your comment is the exact answer of my issue.thx

Answer (score 3):

`DateTime` is not a refence type, so it cannot be null. You can use a nullable date with `DateTime?` (which is the same as `Nullable<DateTime>`) to check for null value.

```cs
DateTime? issueDate = dataReader.GetValue<DateTime?>(DbColumnNames.PLAST_ISSUE_DT);

if (issueDate == null) {
    // Is null
}
```

Or check for the default value of `DateTime`, which should be 01/01/0001.

```cs
DateTime issueDate = dataReader.GetValue<DateTime>(DbColumnNames.PLAST_ISSUE_DT);

if (issueDate == default) {
    // Is default value
}
```

Comment: `DateTime is not a refence type, so it cannot be null.` A minor quibble, but `DateTime?` is _also_ not a reference type (which is why I wouldn't mention that explicitly - it just confuses the issue). Perhaps it would be clearer to say that `DateTime` cannot have the value `null`?

Comment: @mjwills I never said that `DateTime?` is a reference type.

Comment: You never _said_ it, but your argument strongly _implies_ it. You say "X is not Y, you need to use Z instead". At the very least you _imply_ that Z is Y (which, in this case, it isn't) - hence why I said it was best not to argue it in that way. In other words, by saying "DateTime is not a refence type, so it cannot be null" it introduces confusion - since you are suggesting using `DateTime?` which _also_ is not a reference type. So the person reading the answer will be confused. Why does `DateTime?` work even if it isn't a reference type? Hence why I suggested the specific wording that I did.

Answer (score 1):

`DateTime` is a value type so it always evaluates to something. Likewise, if you don't put a value in an `int` the value inside will be 0 and not null.

If you do want to have null then you have to make your database field nullable and use a define `IssueDate` as type `DateTime?` which is Nullable of DateTime and it will be able to hold the null value.